# FTP is not allowed for this user account Error 530

Tags: ftp

Hi this may sound silly but honestly it should be a simple fix but can't figure out why this isn't working.

I have just setup an FTP account on Serv-U application and on testing, I am getting the following error:

```
**530 ftp is not allowed for this user account**
```

No logs anywhere, reset account password - same issue, my IP is allowed still same issue. Anyone come across this before?

Comment: How are you connecting to your FTP server? (Which client/OS?) I think this might be that's giving the error

Comment: testing via ftp command prompt and also via the browser ftp://. I have other accounts setup previously and those accounts still works. So not sure why this new account isn't working. I will create another account and see if issue persist with newly created accounts

Answer (score 0):

OK silly me :), I managed to fix the problem. Basically if you using Serv-U as your FTP/FTPS/SFTP 3rd party application, then you run into this issue in future, go through the following steps to fix the problem:

```
- Open the properties of the affected account
- Click on Limits & Settings tab
- Locate the section 'Allow FTP and FTPS connections' and ensure the value is set to 'Yes'
```

There you are, issue fixed. Sorry for taking your time, i should have known this.